# PATH and file structure

Tags: bash, path

Every time I install a new program must I add it's subdirectory to PATH? or does this statement cover all subdirectories?:`PATH=$PATH:~/local/bin`  in my `.bashrc`

If I must add every subdirectory to PATH is there an automated solution that I can place in `.bashrc`? So that on startup it checks all subdirectories against PATH, if FALSE update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's indeed the case that you have **directories** under `$HOME/local/bin` like

```
$HOME/local/bin/atool
$HOME/local/bin/btool
$HOME/local/bin/ctool
```

and you'd like each of these to be in your `$PATH` then you can do the following in your `.bashrc` or probably your `.bash_login` as you wouldn't want this done every time you start a bash session from an existing one.

```
MYLOCALPATH=`find $HOME/local/bin -type d -depth 1 | paste -s -d : -`
PATH=$PATH:$MYLOCALPATH
```

If that's not the case then perhaps you could be a bit more specific in whats not happening for you as usually exes are usually installed in `<somewhere>/bin` and even if they're not for versioning reasons they'll usually be linked there.

Comment: I think you captured the spirit of my question. I am installing various tools for scientific research. Basically, I download a tar ball and unpack it in my `~/local/bin` which is where my collection of tools are. I just find it annoying to have to add to PATH every time I add a folder in that location.

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about updating the PATH just make sure you only add these special directories once in one place. A variation on the above is to have a file with the PATHS to add and use ``paste`` on that file. As I'm sure you'll end up with directories in your bin dir that you don't want added to your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Programs installed through your package manager or `make install` with no special `./configure` options, will install themselves or at least add a symlink in one of the standard binary directories, such as `/usr/bin/` or sometimes `/usr/games/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.

You do not need to add the programs' data directories to the path.